# ¿Cómo puedo evitar que el cliente vea los directorios donde están los .css de mi sitio?

Tags: css, .htaccess, seguridad

Logro hacerlo modificando el archivo .htaccess con las lineas

Allow from None
Order allow,deny

pero agregando estas lineas, mi propio sitio no carga los archivos .css

Answer (score 0):

No es posible.

Cuando el servidor web recibe una petición este devuelve un archivo, generalmente con codigo html. Dentro de ese archivo aparecen, generalmente, las peticiones que debe hacer el navegador para poder renderizar la página.

Si el navegador no puede acceder al archivo css por que se le está denegando como en este caso no podrá renderizar la página correctamente.

Comment: Temo decirlo para tu desdicha Maximiliano, pero carlos tiene razón,  eso de ocultar las rutas de los CSS es imposible!

Answer (score 0):

No se puede hacer.

No obstante, puedes emplear algunos trucos para intentar que sea "menos accesible". Por ejemplo, puedes utilizar un [ofuscador para css](http://cssobfuscator.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Se me ocurre que con htaccess indiques que, si en la URL tiene un "localhost/css/style.css"  lo lleve a una pagina diferente.

```html
--------------------htaccess--------------------------------
Options All -Indexes
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule css/style.css          carpeta/noting.html
------------------------------------------------------------
```

Y dentro del archivo le pones el mensaje que quieras

```html
--------------------HTML-------------------------------

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2> acceso denegado </h2>
</body>
</html>
```